# Limiting celery concurrency per user

Tags: python, redis, celery

Our implementation receives "bursts" of tasks from our users in a somewhat unpredictable manner (webhooks from a service we don't own).

We need to only process a single task per user at a time. At the moment we're achieving this by using redis locks, and retrying the task if the lock can't be acquired.

It works, but it's not ideal, as often the task queue ends up being full of 90% tasks for a single user, with tasks being requeued dozens of times before they finally get through.

Is anyone aware of a broker that allows for a task to only be sent to a worker if there are no tasks in progress (unacknowledged?) based on some information about the task, perhaps the queue?